# Poor/Incorrect handling of derivatives of DiracDelta functions in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier**

Integration of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2|x|}\delta''(x) dx = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2|x|}\frac{\delta(x)}{x^2} dx \rightarrow$ **Divergent!**

Now in Mathematica-

**1:**

```
v[x_] := DiracDelta[x]
sy[x_] := Exp[-Abs[x]]
Integrate[v''[x]*sy[x]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

It gives: **`-2*Abs''[0]`**. The same answer for `sy[x_]:=Exp[-Sqrt[x^2]].`

**2:**
Now If I re-write `Abs` function as `sy[x_] := Exp[-Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}, 0]];` Then it gives **`4`**. Strange!, (Like in one of the anwsers, has been reported as bug.)

**3:**

```
sy[x_] := Exp[-Abs[x]]
2*Integrate[sy[x]^2 DiracDelta[x]/x^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Now it says: `Integrate::idiv: "Integral of (E^(-2 Abs[x])\DiracDelta[x])/x^2 does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}."`

So I have seen Mathematica, even **Wolfram Alpha** [ [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BDiracDelta%27%5Bx%5D,%20%7Bx,%20-Infinity,Infinity%7D%5D), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-Integrate%5BDiracDelta%5Bx%5D%2Fx,%20%7Bx,%20-Infinity,Infinity%7D%5D) ] fails to deal with derivatives of `DiracDelta` function.

Any resolution, please ?

Please help!

Comment: The integral under consideration $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|x|}\delta(x)/x^2\,dx $ makes no sense in traditional math (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: @user64494, Thanks, I will go though it.  you mean $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \delta''(x) dx$ makes NO Sense  for any f(x)? Could you please say a bit more!

Comment: As it is written in my comment, I have in mind the concrete integral. Hope I am/was clear.

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta''(x)\,dx$ makes no sense too: the $\delta$ -function and its derivatives are not usual functions, but distributions. I have the impression you didn't look in the recommended Wiki article.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following relations

```
DiracDelta'[x]==-DiracDelta[x]/x
DiracDelta''[x]==2!DiracDelta[x]/x^2
```

might help.
The integral evaluates to

```
Limit[2!/x^2 sy[x]^2 ,x->0]->Infinity
```

which confirms your first the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RealAbs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html) instead of [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html):

```
v[x_] = DiracDelta[x];
sy[x_] = Exp[-RealAbs[x]];
Integrate[v''[x]*sy[x]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 4

This is not correct. Bug report has been filed.

Comment: Nice idea, but Mathematica cannot handle the 'derivatives'  of the deltadistribution! The derivatives only exist in the sense of distribution. I'm quite sure that the result `4` is wrong!

Comment: You're right that the result is wrong. Maybe you can file a bug report? Usually Mathematica can deal with derivatives of the Dirac distribution quite well, as in `Integrate[DiracDelta''[x] f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` giving the correct answer `f''[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the problem seems to be  the `RealAbs` function? My version 11.0.1 unfortunately doesn't know this function. What 's the result if you use `Sqrt[x^2]` instead of `Abs[x]`?

Comment: I have "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)". When I use the definition `sy[x_] = Exp[-Sqrt[x^2]]` the result is again `-2 Abs''[0]`.

Comment: That confirms the result in my answer because `-2 Abs''[0]->Infinity`

Comment: Roman, why do you say Mathematica is wrong? If you think `f''[0]` is the correct result for the generic case, then with both `f[x_] := Exp[-RealAbs[x]]^2` and `f[x_]:=Exp[-Sqrt[x^2]]^2`, the result of `Limit[f''[x], x->0]` returns 4.

Comment: @Roman, Thanks, but not helpful, because answer should have been $\infty$!!

Comment: @CarlWoll your derivative is not correct. The second derivative of $\exp(-2|x|)$ is $4\exp(-2|x|)-4\delta(x)$. When you take the limit as $x\to0$ you miss the Dirac delta-function.

Comment: @SachinKumar yes I just filed a bug report.

Comment: I used the form of Dirac delta function `delta[x_] := ep/(Pi*(x^2 + ep^2));
f[x_] := Exp[-Abs[x]];
Limit[Integrate[f[x]^2*delta''[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], ep -> 0] `, But in this case, It gives $-\infty$